# Unable to play sound via headphones in my Asus Rog laptop

Tags: sound, headphones, 21.04

OS: Ubuntu 21.04
Laptop: Asus ROG strix GL503GE-EN041T

When I insert my headphones (3.5 mm jack), the popup also appears to select the audio device. ([Screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/fVD3V.png)) But still sound is not coming via headphones. How to fix this issue?

Comment: Are these USB headphones or do they use a 3.5mm jack?

Comment: @matigo 3.5 mm jack